# juju and keys for multiple administrators

Tags: cloud, juju

We are currently doing some testing to see if Juju will fit our needs to deploy a new application to EC2.  We have three developers that need to be able to make changes to the the deployed instances, but . . .

. . . right now, only the person that bootstrapped juju is the only one who can make changes.  Obviously this doesn't work out very well.

We are aware of the authorized-keys-path and the authorized-keys settings for the environments.yml files, but can't seem to get them to work correctly.  How are they supposed to be setup in order to allow multiple people to administer the deployed instances?

Answer (score 3):

I know its been a little while since this was originally answered but to fill in your follow up question as well as let you know that this is now possible as a native feature in Juju too, e.g. each developer can have their own key or a set of shared keys etc.

All that needs to be done is add it to the environments.yaml in a authorized-keys: stanz like the one I'll show below, and its added on bootstrap and subsequent deploys if updated.

```
environments:
  martha-is-hott:
    ...
    authorized-keys: |
      ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCSkoja9S9nZingSncdJM7Hb+tpDVhWeP4n+X/I+cRVIiAmtugjs8um61OKx+w6CGESINpoNgFxdzST6zUtgM+2EY7JEH4z+kF0HjVZK8tJiu80IUz2xQg2tmEGdoGNIBRMmoMLCkrjpW3jXnCk2qGkChwyiO6Rptn0e6R34SSc5cMT5F0Jco1GafsKJLRQbzYnvueIVh1KotJL0PODdli7EbcmWikW68Y2sgdUENtvSUQf1ZI9QZnDr8QEhyOywgcO0W8205rm4CGv9dyEe5pfmdqnuezFuP8YhkrEruj/oVYymup3T6xzQb6L09fYNK0nryY8klq8+nT7JMIRtHQV joe@blow
      ssh-rsa AAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAyYy6MJwxDvcHOk7g68vOy4DflEwqVfCNpa4PUR9kO9wg3UWasHZXdQ1lj/ybPG1DBmitV7F15puX7rTfCdExZPS3+lO0+QZL+rDEEv8Mu+1jVh+yj8RdZnIiKf5QxfrAKp14g/N2pikDDR5lQNxz85saKNjMDL1E092aU+IvysilZUNMK9gwWTnmFPpGheesHYThyB3MC3miMyXOUmiaAo9kroA94RsyjFRKUZ0X9OJFcCObCVP/TK46+n11gdTmyPOkmGOGOS5d/xqXDjKGzRmkyuFnstxMuusN9iJtdyH0jKG8sUwjueU24qUQiP9dtSFJgUpQ2V80UP6mz3rpBw== where@is-your-sister
      ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDabVVCnORoiGLgRQ6JXdKkqNUhB1bkD7Jf3HSoOhOVWr3tnBZk5/Qyy4FQ5OenQb8qx8EqQrHb52vu8yPzQ2/pGjdbIxoEqWYpcSaYFG2Tw7I4piTmvQ+cyjpYGeJB8DGOm9sHzWpD14pzQgKa9FZc7T9mPhMCiXzruQlW9lKu1lZwHpCgJVi4ImGWltyBjVsTzVLEfqRuyzgpVd9OxBbrrrNWcxp5PgBWbgIdZ/tHVNdaVJcMkSJk8T0WimL1XUHAMLfGCQmWR5KRbzlKIYm/JRqtNjzGqvPqWa9L4Av5UjnSNSp8eGvdXlaPieeuAVQ/dGEnjPgwdtZC33zzH/ZL brandon@ilovewebsites
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

First off, thanks for trying out juju. :)

The unfortunate answer is, you need to have a single shared SSH key that everybody has, and there is no way to automatically update it (you can manually do it with something like parallel ssh and by editing juju's underlying Zookeeper directly).

There's actually a bug report open to improve this here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/834930

This is an important feature, but currently only has a Medium priority, which puts it at the bottom of the list of bugs which need to be fixed to support a broad spectrum of production use cases of Juju. Those bugs are all tagged 'production':

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bugs?field.tag=production

Please mark yourself as "affected" by any of these, and comment if the bug becomes a blocker for you to adopt juju.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  Having a shared key is acceptable for our situation ( we sit within Nerf range of each other ) but what would the actual syntax of the file look like?