# Is it possible to edit same juju environment on different machines?

Tags: juju

If I want to edit my already-deployed environment on multiple machines.
What should I do if I don't want to ssh the origin environment-setting machine?

Comment: What are you trying to change? Could you provide an example of what you have now and what you intend to achieve?

Comment: Suppose today we got an already-deployed environment(on AWS) in the company. What should I do if I want to deploy services in home without connecting to the machine in company?

Answer (score 1):

I think you either have to (in addition to copy the information in the environment file), either use the same SSH key at home, or add multiple administrators keys, see [juju and keys for multiple administrators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98588/juju-and-keys-for-multiple-administrators) (that probably only works for new deployments).